# Android and Google Drive realtime API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

On Google Drive there is a palin text file of 30MB.
Is it possible with Google Drive realtime API to add a line to the end of the file 
(without the downloading it to the device, and uploading it back to the GDrive)?

Comment: Note that the realtime API does upload only diffs, but it would need to be a realtime document, not a plain text file. And 30MB is probalby too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't allow diff updates to file content at the moment. You need to download the file, append a single line and re-upload.

Comment: Sorry for off topic, but is there a Android API for realtime editing?